# ARC based project is able to Analyze or not?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, analyzer

I am working on`xcode 4.6`  with `ARC based project`.

but When I am going to do project `Analyze`, then it's not doing.

So please anyone tell me for `ARC based project` `Analyze` works or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze is working for ARC also, but I am not having any improper memory management in my project.

So Analyze was not giving me any warning for memory leakage and I thought that Analyze is not working in ARC.

All instrument tool is working in ARC too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Analyze works for ARC.

To better help you, are you receiving an error of some sort? If not can you describe what behavior XCode is exhibiting?